# ORACLE: How to use regexp_like to find a string with single quotes between two characters?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to query the DB for all records that have two single quite between characters. Example : We've, who's.

I have the regex https://regex101.com/r/6MtB9j/1  but it doesn't work with REGEXP_LIKE.

Tried this

```
SELECT content
FROM MyTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (content, '(?<=[a-zA-Z])''(?=[a-zA-Z])')
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Oracle regex does not support lookarounds.

Comment: Oh ok.  thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle regex does not support lookarounds.

You do not actually need lookaround in this case, you can use

```sql
SELECT content
FROM MyTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (content, '[a-zA-Z]''[a-zA-Z]')
```

This will work since `REGEXP_LIKE` only attempts one match, and if there is a match, it returns true, otherwise, false (eventually, fetching a record or not).

Lookarounds are useful in case you need to replace or extract values, when matches may overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a single quote in a string, you can use:

where content like '%*''*%'

If they specifically need to be letters, then you need a regular expression:

```
regexp_like(content, '[a-zA-Z][''][a-zA-Z]')
```

or:

```
regexp_like(content, '[a-zA-Z]\'[a-zA-Z]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you may need something like

`regexp_count(content, '[a-zA-Z]''[a-zA-Z]') = 2`.

For example, this

```
with myTable(content) as
(
    select q'[what's]' from dual union all
    select q'[who's, what's]' from dual union all
    select q'[who's, what's, I'm]' from dual
)        
select *
from myTable
where regexp_count(content, '[a-zA-Z]''[a-zA-Z]') = 2
```

gives

```
CONTENT
------------------
who's, what's
```